# Link to home screen widget selector via Intent

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have created an app widget for my app and now I want to tell my users about it by linking to the home screen widget selector from the settings screen of my app.

Is that even possible? I couldn't find a matching Intent action in the documentation.

Comment: The app widget selector is a feature of the launcher implementation, not a part of the OS, AFAICT.

Comment: @CommonsWare ah, I feared so much. :(